# How to fix java warning for "The value of the local variable is not used "

Tags: java

How to avoid java warning which says

> The value of the  local variable is not used

for the variable which is declared as `private`?

Comment: Your IDE is letting you know that this variable is never used in your code.  So you _may_ be able to completely delete it with no consequences.

Comment: The best way to avoid this message, is to use the variable, if not suppress the variable.

Comment: I believe your question contradicts itself. If warning text says "local variable", then it's not a *field* and cannot be declared `private`. The warning for a private field would say "The value of the **field** is not used". Well, at least that's what Eclipse does.

Comment: @Andreas yes, it's " the value of the field "

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple choices:

1. Remove the field.
   It is unused, so it shouldn't be there.
2. Comment out the field, e.g. using `// TODO`
   Good for temporary hiding of warning until you write code using field.
3. Suppress the warning using `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.
4. Disable the warning in IDE settings. For Eclipse, that would be in

   - `Window` > `Preferences`
   - `Java` > `Compiler` > `Error/Warnings`
   - `Unnecessary code` > `Unused private member`
   - Select option `Ignore`

For #3 and #4, though, although you can, why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not used and does not contain any code you are interested in, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying because the value of the variable or variable is not used within the program. So to remove this warning you can simply delete this variable because you are not using it anywhere .Or use this variable at some point in your code

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in some cases it's not that easy. Here's an example of why it's not as easy as just commenting out the code. Sure this is a comment, but I don't have rep of 50 to comment and the comment block is lame anyway. So sue me. This does not work by the way, but comments are lame here.

```
try {
    // so, rather than a wait, we check for exit value
    // and if that tosses an exception, the process is
    // still running. Ooooooookkkkkaaaaaayyyyyy No Problem
    int exitValue = pShowProcess.exitValue();
    // guess we don't do this to get rid of the not referened warning
    //(void)exitValue;
    // we don't care what the exit value was
    exitValue = 0;
    // but if we get here, then the show stopped, so
    // if we stop it now, it won't need to wait, it will be fine
    // we think.
    endShow();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Process is still running. So just keep going until
    // mouse clicks or something else stops the show
}
```