# Getting an Error in Java when creating a variable for my Option Dialog

Tags: java, swing

```
package hellojava;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Samira
 */
public class HelloJava {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name, surname, message;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Hello!");
        name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
        surname= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your last name?");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select the appropriate age"
          + " for joining Java Programming", "Information", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


        Object[] options= {"Age 18-21", "Age 22+"};
        int userage= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How old are you?",
            "An Age Question",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[1]);

        message= String.format("Welcome" + name + " " + surname + " to Java Programming!");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }//end main
}//end class HelloJava
```

This is the code and I'm getting the error at line 18

Comment: It would probable be helpfull for us if we could see the error message.

Comment: i was informed its a warning and not an error. Where is says "Variable userage is not used... Object[] options= {"Age 18-21", "Age 22+"};
        int userage= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "How old are you?",
                "An Age Question",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[1]);

Answer (score 5):

I tried creating an empty Java project with your code.  What I get from the compiler is the following warning: "The value of the local variable userage is not used".

First of all, this message is a warning message, not an error.  A distinction between those is that an error prevents the code from compiling, while when there is a warning message the code will compile.  However, a warning hints a problem that should still probably be adressed, because often the program's behavior might not be the one desired.

In your case, the compiler detects that you declare your variable "userage", but as we can see, this variable is never used later so declaring it doesn't serve any purpose.  If you actually use this variable later, for instance to perform a boolean condition to validate the age, or save it into a file, or simply output it using a JOptionPane, then the compiler will detect you're using the variable and won't think this variable is useless.

As an example, try adding this line after the declaration of "userage":

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You selected the choice options[" + Integer.toString(userage) + "].");
```

This will output the value of your variable, which represent the index of the selection option from your "options" array, so the variable will now be used.

Also, when posting a question it really helps, as Niek T. mentionned, to add all the information you have: what is the problem, what exact message do you get from the compiler, what happens when you launch the program, etc.  That way, helpers can answer much faster as they don't need to create a project with your code in it, as I dit.

For further reading, I found similar threads with the same question:
[How to fix java warning for "The value of the local variable is not used "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917187/how-to-fix-java-warning-for-the-value-of-the-local-variable-is-not-used)